# Returning only the filtered tree from fancytree

Tags: javascript, json, filter, fancytree

Please help.

This is probably very simple, but I've been stuck on it  for days.

As the title says, I want to get only the filtered tree including parent nodes in [fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) (for `json` purposes).

I've looked at [ext-filter](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtFilter), but it doesn't seem to directly provide any `getRootNode` or `findAll` functions.

How do I retrieve the filtered version of a tree?

Comment: Wheres your code? Shows us what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

It can be don like so:

```js
var nodeList = tree.toDict(false, function(d, node){

  if( !node.isMatched() && !node.subMatchCount) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

> (Note: the `toDict` callback supports returning `false` only since Fancytree version 2.32. Until then, you have to workaround using `tree.visit(callback)`, `node.toDict(false)`, etc.)